# Datetime offset 2 hours

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, search-results, content-search-web-part

I have edited my display template for my content search web part. I have added a new managed property to my display template. The managed property is a datetime field wich is mapped to the recently modified field. It displays the time but 2 hours offset, 2 hours wrong. I live in timezone gmt + 2, how can i display it 2+ gmt?

Comment: Does the SQL Server and the Windows Servers in the Farm use GMT (and not GMT+2) in their system time setting?

Comment: It is sharepoint online, the locale setting is gmt +2, swedish.

Comment: Did you ever find any solution to this? Been stuck for days.